# What is the context of nostalgia?

Tags: emotion, evolution, survival

People often have old watches, old cars or some old articles which are not functional but they don't feel like throwing them away. So what purpose does such a feeling serve and how is it helpful or harmful for our survival?

Comment: Presumably having nostalgic things around helps to recall context-sensitive memories, including non-declarative memories, which keeps one grounded. On a darker note, reeducation camps and cults may seek to remove any cues from one's past so as to minimise memory, including previous learned behaviours.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. More specifically, if I don't sell old things, will it not have its own problems like too much clutter and unorganized homes and spaces. Also, from an evolutionary point of view, how beneficial or otherwise is nostalgia? Does it have any evolutionary significance at all? Does memory have any evolutionary significance at all?

Comment: Indeed *hoarding* can become a disorder in itself. Perhaps keeping only the most memorable items is most efficient. Pictures or recordings as well can be space-saving. Emotions serve to empower circumstantially beneficial action. While only a hypothesis, maybe nostalgia aims to remind us to take a moment in the presence of our past *perceptual set* to reflect on how our current circumstances compare with our past and our prior expectations. The greater awareness we have of life's possibilities (both good and bad), the more informed our future actions. Nostalgia is a time to reflect.

Comment: indeed a very useful comment, Thank you! Could you care to post an answer citing some sources too please?